# How to append list inside list to rows in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How to append list inside list to rows in Excel?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('State.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.active

lst = [['Wed Mar 24 20:07:56 2021'], ['ODS'], ['191'], ['254(215AA)'], ['2'], ['93(54AA)'], ['189'], ['161(161AA)'],
       ['19:00'], ['19:31']]

for x in lst:
    sheet_1.append(x)

wb.save('State.xlsx')
```

I'm expecting:

[image]

But result is:

[image]

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this part of your code:

```
for x in lst:
    sheet_1.append(x)
```

with this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    sheet_1.cell(1, i+1).value = x[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The append method with a single scalar param appends a sinlge value to a new row.
Use append with a dictionary to append multiple values into a single row.
Each key in the dictionary identifies a column by its index, or its name.

```
append({column_index: value,....})
```

or

```
append({"column_name": value, "coulmn2_name": value, ...})
```

see more details and examples [on openpyxl docs site](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=append#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append)